# How to find unnecessary joins in a SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently maintaining a significant number of existing SQL queries. Is there any way to find unnecessary joins in a SQL query by using execution plan or any other alternate method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "unnecessary join".  Can you give me an example?

Comment: The only way I could imagine a join is not useful is when you don't subsequently refer to it again in a another join or the select clause. I would think this would be very rare in practice unless you had incompetent people writing the queries in the first place.

Comment: "Is there any way to find unnecessary joins in a SQL query by using execution plan or any other alternate method." No.  Assuming by unnecessary you mean the fields within the table are not displayed nor included in a where clause, order, or group by. The join could still be valid to limit... or explode results (such as in a cross join)

Comment: @xQbert That is not true.  Try an outer join that is not used and does not effect the query.  I did and it is not even in the execution plan.  That said it is easier to actually evaluate the query then to hunt down what the query plan does not use.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you examined even a single query with an unnecessary join? Post an example of an unnecessary join and what you discovered in the query plan and I will take away the -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no magic tool out there that will scour your database and bring up a list of things that might possibly be 'unnecessary'. Rahul's answer points you in the right direction, looking through the queries and comparing them to an ERD and spec.

Execution plans can help you identify if a particular query is performing poorly, and it might be that the reason is unnecessary joins, but it could as well be anything else, too.

In the end it comes down to knowing your database, knowing the data, and how it's used.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ERD (Entity Relationship diagram) in place along with the `business requirement specification` for the said query; then by looking at the ERD and SPEC; I believe you can at least get an idea if there is any relation with which a join is not (may not be) necessary.